# Equivalent of jQuery.active in javascript Selenium Web Driver

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using Selenium webdriver to interact with some website.
If the website is using jQuery we can get the pending AJAX request by using `jQuery.active`:

```
 JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

> <strike>Int totAjaxRequest = (Int)jsx.executeScript("jQuery.active");</strike>

```
Int totAjaxRequest = (Int)jsx.executeScript("return jQuery.active");
```

In case if the website is not using jQuery, how could we count the number of `XMLHttpRequest` requests?

Comment: Or can I use event listener for every `XMLHttpRequest` request and increment a counter ...

Comment: Can any one can give some hint also that would help me.

Answer (score 1):

Keep this in your website, and call it from selenium. I think there is no any similar built in js function. I don't think this is the answer you are looking for, but as I said above javascript does not have such a function itself.

If you can not edit or add new script to your website, you can still run the script.

```
Int totAjaxRequest = (Int)jsx.executeScript("
    (function(){
        var count = 0;
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.nativeSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(body) {

            this.onreadystatechange  = function(){
               switch(this.readyState){
                   case 2: count++; break
                   case 4: count--; break
               }
            };
            this.nativeSend(body);
        };

        return count;
    })()

");
```

Comment: The website does not belongs to me. So I can not add some code there. Is there any way in selenium by which I can inject some function/script in the website.

Comment: just wrap that script only function part to Int totAjaxRequest = (Int)jsx.executeScript("{{here}}"); Answer is updated

Comment: it's difficult to use.the above function because it reinitize the counter every time

Answer (score 1):

Here an example how the waiting for AJAX requests can be done with nightwatch custom commands.

One command to init the counter. on every `send` if will increase the counter and on ever `open` it will decrease it `customCommands/initAjaxCounters.js`:

```
exports.command = function () {
  this.execute(function () {
    window.sumStartedAjaxRequests = 0
    window.activeAjaxCount = 0

    function isAllXhrComplete () {
      window.activeAjaxCount--
    }

    (function (open) {
      XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
        this.addEventListener('loadend', isAllXhrComplete)
        return open.apply(this, arguments)
      }
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open)
  })
  this.execute(function () {
    (function (send) {
      XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
        window.activeAjaxCount++
        window.sumStartedAjaxRequests++
        return send.apply(this, arguments)
      }
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send)
  })
  return this
}
```

and then an other custom command to wait

```
const sleepWhenOutstandingAjaxCalls = function (result) {
  if (result.value > 0) {
    this.pause(this.globals.waitForConditionPollInterval)
    this.waitForOutstandingAjaxCalls()
  }
}

exports.command = function () {
  // init the ajax counter if it hasn't been initialized yet
  this.execute('return (typeof window.activeAjaxCount === "undefined")', [], function (result) {
    if (result.value === true) {
      throw Error('checking outstanding Ajax calls will not work without calling initAjaxCounter() first')
    }
  })

  this.execute(
    'return window.activeAjaxCount', [], sleepWhenOutstandingAjaxCalls
  )
  return this
}
```